# sizeof for a matrix of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, sizeof

The comments fairly explains it all. Help?

```
   string aZOM[][2] = {{"MoraDoraKora", "PleaseWorkFFS"},{"This is a nother strang.", "Orly?"}};
cout << sizeof("MoraDoraKora") <<" \n";
//Obviously displayes the size of this string...
cout << sizeof(aZOM[0][0]) << " \n";
//here's the problem, it won't display the size of the actual string... erm, what?

string example = aZOM[0][0];
cout << example << " \n";
cout << aZOM[0][1] << " \n";
//Both functions display the string just fine, but the size of referencing the matrix is the hassle.
```

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` gives you the size of the object you pass to it in bytes. If you give it a `std::string`, it gives you the size of the `std::string` object itself. Now that object my dynamically allocate storage for the actual characters and contain a pointer to them, but that's not part of the object itself.

To get the size of a `std::string`, use its [`size`/`length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member function:

```
cout << aZOM[0][1].size() << " \n";
```

The reason `sizeof("MoraDoraKora")` works fine is because the string literal `"MoraDoraKora"` is *not* a `std::string` object. It's type is "array of 13 `const` `char1`" and so `sizeof` reports the size of that array in bytes.

Comment: Note; for the first one you get the size of a const char*?

Comment: this seems the better explanation. :)

Comment: @Skeen You get the size of the array because the array doesn't undergo array-to-pointer conversion as an operand of `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` return the size of the type, not the size of the data pointed to.

A string is usually a pointer to char, where the last char in the chain has the value 0.

if you want the actual size of the string, you might use `aZOM[0][0].length()`